# How to pass param programmatically using route instead of ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, parameters

I have a state like this in $stateProvider

```
$stateProvider.state('rubricacontatti.home', {
  url: '/home/:section',
  templateUrl: 'rubricacontatti/static/html/rubricacontatti.home.html',
});
```

and I must pass param section programmatically without using ui-sref or $state.go. Due to project choises I'm constrained to use this:

```
      route: 'rubricacontatti.home'
```

How can I pass param to route?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are programmatically getting the value but the `stateConfig` has a `params` property that takes an object with any number of properties. Should be able to set it their.

```
$stateProvider.state('rubricacontatti.home', {
    url: '/home/:section',
    templateUrl: 'rubricacontatti/static/html/rubricacontatti.home.html',
    params: {
       myParam1: "programmatically set value"
    }
});
```

See the `$stateProvider` [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider).